# mongoose disconnect on for loop end in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, for-loop, mongoose

I want to populate an instance of mongodb with some bogus data through a nodejs script and i want to call mongoose.disconnect() when the for loop is done so that the program doesn't continue looping because of the mongoose instance.

The problem is, because nodejs is non-blocking in the current code, it calls the for loop and then continues and exits.
I've tried something with the async lib but can't figure out exactly how i can make this work.

What is the proper way of doing this in node?

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    promise = require('promise');

mongoose.Promise = promise;
    var uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'

var test1Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    type: String
});

var test2Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    type: String
});

var test3Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    type: String
});

var test1 = mongoose.model('test1', test1Schema);
var test2 = mongoose.model('test2', test2Schema);
var test3 = mongoose.model('test3', test3Schema);

function genRandom (high, low) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low) + low);
}

mongoose.connect(uri);

var _connection = mongoose.connection;

_connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Couldn\'t connect to the database %s - %s', uri, err);
});

_connection.on('open', function () {
    console.log('Connection open - ', uri);
});

_connection.on('close', function () {
    console.log('Closed mongoose connection');
});

var saveCallback = function (err) {
    if (err) {
    console.log('An error occured while saving %s', err);
    }
}

function genRecords (callback) {
    for (var i=0; i <= 5; i++) {
    new test1({
        name: 'test_' + i.toString(),
        type: genRandom(123, 321).toString()
    }).save(callback);

    new test2({
        name: 'test_' + i.toString(),
        type: genRandom(456, 654).toString()        
    }).save(callback);

    new test3({
        name: 'test_' + i.toString(),
        type: genRandom(789, 987).toString()        
    }).save(callback);
    }
}

genRecords(saveCallback)

mongoose.disconnect();
```

The output:

```
Connection open -  mongodb://localhost:27017/test
Closed mongoose connection
An error occured while saving MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
An error occured while saving MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
An error occured while saving MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
An error occured while saving MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
An error occured while saving MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
An error occured while saving MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
An error occured while saving MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
An error occured while saving MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
An error occured while saving MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
An error occured while saving MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
An error occured while saving MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
An error occured while saving MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
An error occured while saving MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
An error occured while saving MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
An error occured while saving MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
An error occured while saving MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
An error occured while saving MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
An error occured while saving MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
```

Answer (score 0):

You must think that you work with *asynchronous functions*. So you're preparing your `save()` functions, but they finished **after** the disconnection.

You need to wait the end of your `save()` call. Two solutions :

- use promises (for example with [**bluebird**](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird))
- use [**async**](https://github.com/caolan/async) module

Answer (score -1):

Use this module http://caolan.github.io/async/

Then do this code.

```
async.times(5, function(i, done){
    //run in here your 3 instances with async.waterfall or something like this then go to next iteration
    methodToSave3Instances(i, done);
}, function(err) {
   mongoose.disconnect();
});

function methodToSave3Instances(i , cb) {
   async.waterfall([
     function(callback) {
        new test1({
          name: 'test_' + i.toString(),
          type: genRandom(123, 321).toString()
        }).save(callback);
     },
     function(callback) {
         new test2({
           name: 'test_' + i.toString(),
           type: genRandom(123, 321).toString()
        }).save(callback);
     },
    function(callback) {
        new test3({
           name: 'test_' + i.toString(),
           type: genRandom(123, 321).toString()
        }).save(callback);
    }
   ], function (err, result) {
       cb();
   });
}
```